# How to get commented intellisense in VS Code

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, c++11

Does anyone know how to get comments from above your created functions to show up in intellisense in visual studio code? im wanting it for use with C++ and on linux. Im not sure exactly how to describe this so ive included a picture below, hopefully that helps.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It accepts notation to codedoc or doxyGen, well, compatible with DoxyGen and similar tools, e.g.:

`///` - C# (and I think, C++ of recent versions)

`'''` - VisualBasic

Comment: any idea how i can get this in visual studio code with C++ though? like an extension or something?

Comment: @tim oliver what version you use? Are you sure it's not woking in  C++? did you searched though plugins? I saw there was one called Document This once upon a time, it used closure\JSDoc form which essentially supported same format